# Solving a complex line integral via Stokes' Theorem

Tags: stokes-theorem

I haven't a clue how to set up my double integral to solve this question

[image: The question]

The answer, according to the textbook, is:

[image]

> Since $curl F = 1/(1+y^2)i + 2ze^{x^2}j + y^2k$

Ummm... What? Am I missing something? Where did that come from?!

Comment: Good question +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare
$$\oint z^2e^{x^2}dx+xy^2dy+\arctan y \, dz$$
with
$$\oint F_x \,dx+F_y \,dy+F_z \,dz$$
to see that the vector field in this case is given by $\vec F = \left( z^2e^{x^2},xy^2,\arctan y\right)$.

Now compute the curl, e.g. via
$$\mbox{curl} \vec F =\begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x} & \tfrac{\partial}{\partial y} & \tfrac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
F_x & F_y & F_z
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x} & \tfrac{\partial}{\partial y} & \tfrac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
z^2e^{x^2} & xy^2 &\arctan y
\end{vmatrix} = \cdots$$

Comment: Wow, super obvious now that I look at it. I just hadn't considered that F already "existed" in the given equation

Comment: Sometimes you just don't see it! :)